# How can i get value from arraylist and store it in a list which is in a different class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following method which sets the price of items:

**Main Class**

```
public void setShoePrice(){
    int selectionNumber = shoeList.getSelectedIndex();
    Double[] shoesPrices = {1.00, 2.00, 3.00};
    Basket.shoePrice+= shoePrices[selectionNumber];
}
```

I also have another class which is the shoeLibrary class and this is where the arraylist of shoes is kept.

**ShoeLibrary Class**

```
public class ShoeLibrary {

private ArrayList<Shoe> shoes;

public ShoeLibrary() {
    shoes = new ArrayList<Shoe>();
    shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 1", 1.00));
    shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 2", 2.00));
    shoes.add(new Shoe("Shoe 3", 3.00));
}
```

So at the moment if i want to change the price of the shoes i have to update them in the ShoeLibrary Class as well as in my method. How can i do it so that the list in the method gets the values from the array list in my ShoeLibrary Class.

Note. I have another class called Shoes which has setters and getters for the array list in the ShoeLibrary class.

I have tried creating the following method but cant seem to get it to assign the values to the shoePrices list in the method.

```
public Double[] getShoePrices() {

    Double[] prices = new Double[shoes.size()];

    for (int index = 0; index < shoes.size(); index++) {
        prices[index] = shoes.get(index).getShoePrice();
    }
    return prices;
}
```

Im new to java so thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I am using this in the class where my setShoePrice method is:

```
public Double[] getShoePrice(){
        ShoeLibrary s = new ShoeLibrary();
        Double prices[] = s.getShoePrices();
        return prices;
    }
```

And for the arraylist in the method im doing it as follows:

```
Double[] shoesPrices = {getShoePrice()};
```

Comment: What is the FilmLibrary class?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. I have edited it now

Comment: Why cant you get it? Which error do you receive?

Comment: @PavloPlynko i have updated my code

Comment: So, which error do you receive?

Comment: @PavloPlynko Type mismatch: cannot convert from Double[] to Double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
Double[] shoesPrices = {getShoePrice()};
```

with this:

```
Double[] shoesPrices = getShoePrice();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are doing in `setShoePrice` method:

- Call a method that gets an array of all prices
- Find the selected price
- Add it to basket

This way, you are maintaining shoe prices twice (one in shoe library and other in `double[]` array. Due to this, if shoe price gets updated in the library, your array still holds the stale copy and hence, it returns the old price.

A fix would be to remove the use of `double[]` array and get the price directly from library, e.g.:

```
public Double getShoePrice(int index){
   if(index >= shoes.size()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index");
   }
   return shoes.get(index).getPrice();
}
```

Comment: No it's not in that class and secondly I want to have the price in an array as stated in the question.

Comment: Could you please post the whole class code in that case?